# How to fix hardhat InternalError: Unknown transaction type 106 Error?

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js, hardhat

I am writing a generic hardhat test for some mullti chain stats of a contract
For example
I have a function named ***createRaffle*** i run a hardhat test on it
within the test. Hardhat first tests it on forked latest block ETH then resets the network and forks latest block polygon and tests on it and gives me stats like gas used, gas cost etc.
This all works fine as intended all within hardhat test file
but when I add a network like arb or base
it throws error :

```
An unexpected error occurred:
InternalError: Unknown transaction type 106
```

*how to fix this ?*

This is my code that resets the network

```
// Network Fork Setup 
const helpers = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");

const RPC = configService.getRPC(networkName);
console.log(`\n\t*** RPC = ${RPC} ***`);
await helpers.reset(RPC);
return;
// This works fine for eth and polygon but not for Arbitrum mainnet or Base ( coinbase )
```

Since the code is generic so I have **RPC** variable in .env file. It picks network RPC from there. Whatever network I will be using. RPC has no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue using
https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/2995

> Certain EVM blockchain (e.g. Arbitrum Nitro) have non-standard EIP-2718 typed transaction that would prevent hardhat fork from working due to Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: Unknown transaction type 106

I installed

```
npm i hardhat@npm:@gzeoneth/hardhat@2.10.1-gzeon-c8fe47dd4
```

Now hardhat network reset just ignores the arbitrum unknown transaction type.

```
await network.provider.request({
method: "hardhat_reset",
params: [
  {
    forking: {
      jsonRpcUrl: config.networks.hardhat.forking.url,
      blockNumber,
      ignoreUnknownTxType: true,
    },
  },
],
});
```

This now works fine for me.